# Unable to connect socket client (reactjs) to socket server (express) over lan network (different machine on same network)

Tags: reactjs, express, socket.io

I have two different machines connect to same network.

I wanted to connect over LAN Network using LAN assigned IP address below is the simple demonstration

Socket Client (Reactjs, IP : 192.168.0.103) to Socket Server (Express, IP :192.168.0.114)

Problem :
Getting error : Access blocked by CORS (tried express 'cors' middleware but failed with no solution)

Here is Simple React Code which is working fine

```
import socketClient from 'socket.io-client';
const SocketServer = 'http://192.168.0.114:3000';

function App() {

  var socket = socketClient(SocketServer, {secure: true});

  socket.emit('client_connected', { payload: {
    message: "react client is connected"
  }});

  return (
    <div>
      
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

And simple express code (which also working fine)

```
const cors = require('cors')
const express = require('express')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')

const app  = express()
const http = require('http')
const server = http.createServer(app)
const { Server } = require('socket.io')
const io = new Server(server)


app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}))
app.use(express.static('public'))

app.use(cors({
    origin: '*'
}));

app.set('view engine', 'ejs')

app.get('/', (req,res) => {

    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html')
})

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    socket.on('client_connected', (message) => {
        console.log(message)
    })
})

server.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

Error screenshot getting in Browser console on ReatJs

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7GYib.png)

I tried setting up headers in express but getting same error

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to configure cors in the socket server not express

take a look here to know more about the configuration https://socket.io/docs/v3/handling-cors/

### configuration example

```js
const io = require("socket.io")(httpServer, {
  cors: {
    origin: "https://example.com",
    methods: ["GET", "POST"]
  }
});
```

Comment: It worked !! thanks a lot @Abdelrhman I appreciate that you responded so quickly

Comment: @visiondecoder no problem.